# Pricing options with 0 or negative underlying values

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, option-strategies, commodities

I am trying to calculate the value of an option whose underlying is the calendar spread between two months for a commodity (front month Brent vs 2nd month), usually known as a calendar spread option.

I am avoiding a CSO model as I do not know where to find implied correlation marks. However, when using the BS model I am running into issues as this spread can be negative when the market is in contango, or zero.

Answer (score 1):

You could just consider the calendar spread as a single variable.   Depending on the commodity you might be able to convince yourself that it is approximated well by a normal distribution, in which case you can estimate the dollar standard deviation from historical data and then you have a simple Bachelier type modeling problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two analytical models for pricing spread options: i) the [Margrabe model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margrabe%27s_formula) for the exchange of two assets (i.e. an option on the spread with strike zero), ii) the [Kirk model](http://help.cqg.com/cqgic/default.htm#!Documents/kirksapproximation.htm) for options on spreads with non-zero strike.

For both of them, you will need to specify a correlation coefficient $\rho$. Using BS is not possible, since it does not allow for negative prices, which is possible in spread options. Furthermore, commodity price spreads will be distributed in a significantly non-lognormal fashion, which any BS-type model is not able to capture.

Where there are no prices to infer implied correlations, I usually look at how historical correlations evolved over time. Depending on whether bid or ask prices need to be determined, i will use levels at the high or low end of the range. Hope that helps...